# Translate the Properties File from one language to another using ResourceBundle

Tags: java, properties, locale, resourcebundle, country

I have message.properties file. by default it will load as English when I use Locale and Resource Bundle in Java file. Now, I need to specify the Country Code or Type in Locale, Then the message.properties file key values should be load as the specified Country in Locale. How can I do this.?

Comment: [The Java Tutorial, Lesson:Internationalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has some example code of this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html).

Basically you create bundles with the correct name for the language of the `Locale`and then load it with:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("LabelsBundle", currentLocale);
```

More information about [internationalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/index.html)..

Also, before asking a question try googling for yourself....